# NN Batch and Training accuracy

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-2

I have NN based on InceptionV3. 
Feeding it batches during epochs gives good results like:

```
loss: 0.3596 - acc: 0.8479 - val_loss: 0.3442 - val_acc: 0.8515
```

After training was done I have decided to check training accuracy on the whole training dataset.

```
sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(labels, np.round(train_predictions))
```

gave me 0.52520718232044195

How that is possible?

Comment: You should evaluate your model on the test set not on the training set.

Comment: Yep, I understand this. I think if classifier does good job it should show accuracy better than random guessing (now it is about 50% for 2 class classifier!) on the training dataset too.

Comment: True :D Why are you rounding the predictions?

Comment: Because NN outputs probabilities. Labels are ints - zeros and ones, so I would like to know how many samples from predictions should be considered as "true" and "false", so I am rounding.

Answer (score 2):

50% was because data sent to 'predict' was completely different from the one it was trained on because of the bug in preprocessing.